# how to parse xml with php

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I am trying to read a weather feed from Yahoo to my site. 
Using the code below I was able to print the xml.
What I really want to achieve now is to put the temperature and image in two different variables

```
 $zipCode = "44418";
 $url = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss";
 $zip = "?w=$zipCode";
 $fullUrl = $url . $zip.'&u=c';
 $curlObject = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curlObject,CURLOPT_URL,$fullUrl);
 curl_setopt($curlObject,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
 curl_setopt($curlObject,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
 $returnYahooWeather = curl_exec($curlObject);
 curl_close($curlObject);
 print "yahooWeather". $returnYahooWeather;

//$temperature 
//$image
```

Comment: So you're discounting your best solution (a [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)) immediately? Sounds promising.

Comment: I agree with the answers below, using simplexml or DOM should do it.  But you also shouldn't be printing/echoing from inside preprocess functions. Instead, create a variable that can be used in a template. For instance `$variables['temperature'] = TEMP CODE HERE;` then in the template you just have to do `<?php print $temperature; ?>`

Comment: @Laxman13, i am aware of that, thanks. just needed to see what was going on first before heading to tpl.php file :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should go ahead and use [simplexml](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to parse the XML and then you can iterate over the results. With SimpleXML this looks like this:

```
$zipCode = "44418";
$url = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss";
$zip = "?w=$zipCode";
$fullUrl = $url . $zip.'&u=c';
$curlObject = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlObject,CURLOPT_URL,$fullUrl);
curl_setopt($curlObject,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
curl_setopt($curlObject,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$returnYahooWeather = curl_exec($curlObject);
curl_close($curlObject);
//print "here". $returnYahooWeather;

$xmlobj=simplexml_load_string($returnYahooWeather);

$res = $xmlobj->xpath("//yweather:condition");
$tmp = false;
while(list( , $node) = each($res)) {
  $tmp = $node;
 }
$attribs = $tmp->attributes();
print "Temperature [".$attribs['temp']."]";
```

Comment: thank you, it works but i do not understand what is being done in the loop while(list( , $node) = each($res)) { ..Please explain if you don't mind.

Comment: That's just laziness on my part. If there was more than one `yweather:condition` element, then that would iterate over them all. In this case, where there is only 1, it just gets that one item. I'm sure there's a way to do it without that loop, but this was quicker since I had the code lying around.

Answer (score 2):

I find it easiest to [SimpleXML](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) with PHP.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($returnYahooWeather);
echo $xml->Path->To->Temperature;
```

It's easy enough, and you can use XPath with SimpleXML :). There are other ways of parsing XML too, as previously mentioned DOMDocument is one of them.